# In Scala Reflection, why do constructor params hide getters?

Tags: scala, reflection

`var`s in a scala class automatically get getters & setters you can see through scala reflection via `members`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
class A(var x: Int)

scala> ru.typeOf[A].members.filter{_.name.toString.contains("x")}
res22: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(variable x, method x_=, method x)
```

However, if you create a subclass, which re-uses the var name in the constructor, the getter is gone:

```
class B(x:Int, var y: Int) extends A(x)
scala> ru.typeOf[B].members.filter{_.name.toString.contains("x")}
res23: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(value x, method x_=)
scala> res23.head.asTerm.isVal
res25: Boolean = true
```

This seems a little misleading ... after all, `B` still does have a getter for `x` (and its not a `val`)

```
scala> val b = new B(5,6)
b: B = B@270288ed

scala> b.x
res26: Int = 5

scala> b.x = 7
b.x: Int = 7

scala> b.x
res27: Int = 7
```

If I try to pretend that the `value x` I got from `members` is a getter, I get an error:

```
scala> val xGetter = res23.head.asTerm
xGetter: reflect.runtime.universe.TermSymbol = value x

scala> val objMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(b)
objMirror: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for B@270288ed

scala> val getterMirror = objMirror.reflectField(xGetter)
scala.ScalaReflectionException: Scala field x isn't represented as a Java field, neither it has a Java accessor method
note that private parameters of class constructors don't get mapped onto fields and/or accessors,
unless they are used outside of their declaring constructors.
```

What is the right workaround here?  Is it completely wrong to have a subclass name its constructor args the same as the names in the parent args?  Or instead of calling `members`, do I need to work my up all super-classes to get all getters & setters?

Note that `members` gives me the inherited getter as long as the subclass doesn't create a constructor w/ the same name:

```
class Y(var x: Int)
class Z(q:Int, z: Int) extends Y(q)
scala> ru.typeOf[Z].members.filter{_.name.toString.contains("x")}
res28: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(method x_=, method x)
```

**EDIT**
In case its unclear, I'm really asking:
1) is this a bug in scala reflection?
2) if not, should I:
(a) never have classes use names of constructor fields be the same as the name of fields in base classes?  (if so, I'm probably defining all my classes wrong ...)
or
(b) to get all getters & setters, should I just go through the list of all parent classes and use `declarations`, rather than relying on `members` to do the right thing, since it doesn't work in this one case?

**EDIT 2**
in response to @som-snytt's answer, the visible methods of `x` are really on `x` in `A`, not the param in the constructor to `B`.  Eg.:

```
class A(var x: Int){def showMeX {println(x)}}
class B(x:Int, var y: Int) extends A(x)
scala> val b = new B(5,10)
scala> b.showMeX
5
scala> b.x = 17
b.x: Int = 17
scala> b.showMeX
17
```

so I don't really think that the either the getter or setter for `x` has been shadowed, from the perspective of normal user code.  Its only been shadowed for reflection code ... and it doesn't make sense to me that there would be two different versions of shadowing.

Comment: this seems to be a bug, please report it [here](http://issues.scala-lang.org/), there it can be told for sure.

Comment: thanks @sschaef, reported here https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8096

Comment: @som-snytt ha, yeah I've been a lurker for a long time, just getting active ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 2) if not, should I: (a) never have classes use names of constructor fields be the same as the name of fields in base classes?

Since they wouldn't let me fix this, that's exactly what I do. I try to give all constructor parameters new names distinct from all inherited names. Here's a typical example within the compiler.

```
class PackageClassSymbol protected[Symbols] (owner0: Symbol, pos0: Position, name0: TypeName)
```

Yes, it's ridiculous.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/9jLsT_RRQR0
- https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3194
- https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4762
- https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6880

Oh boy, don't keep pulling that thread...

- https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7475
- https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2568
- https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6794

It shouldn't be hard to see that the odds of any of it being addressed are nil. It's a perfect example of why I quit.

By the way, if you use -Xlint it warns you about this. That's mentioned in SI-4762.

```
% cat a.scala
class A(var x: Int)
class B(x:Int, var y: Int) extends A(x) {
  def z = x
}

% scalac -Xlint a.scala
a.scala:3: warning: private[this] value x in class B shadows mutable x inherited from class A.
Changes to x will not be visible within class B - you may want to give them distinct names.
  def z = x
          ^
one warning found
```

Comment: it hurt to accept this, but the evidence is pretty overwhelming.  time to rewrite all my code ...

Comment: @ImranRashid in which lang? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in:

```
class B(x:Int, var y: Int) extends A(x)
```

The `x` in `B` is private (not a case class, no `val` or `var` specifier), the x in A is public (you specified `var`).  I'm not too familiar with this reflection API, but does it show private members?

If you instead:

```
scala> class B(val x:Int, var y: Int) extends A(10)
<console>:9: error: overriding variable x in class A of type Int;
 value x needs `override' modifier
       class B(val x:Int, var y: Int) extends A(10)
                   ^
```

The only public x is the one in A, which can be shown here:

```
scala> class B(x:Int, var y: Int) extends A(10)
defined class B

scala> new B(2,3).x
res4: Int = 10
```

If you want to override the parent member, use `override`, and change the parent to something that can be overriden.

Comment: Right, I think you misunderstood the question.  I know the normal non-reflection scala behavior.  And that's great.  The problem is, through scala reflection, I don't get access to the *public* x, that is defined in A.  (at least, I don't get access via the "members" method, I can step through all parents to get everything, but seems unnecessarily complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess as long as the answer to my question is not (2a), then if anybody else runs into this, here is a workaround.  Maybe it will be unnecessary in the future depending on the answer to (1).

(Some extra stuff here, but maybe useful also)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
object ReflectionUtils {
  def extractGetterSetterPairs(typ: ru.Type): Seq[GetterSetterPair] = {
    typ.baseClasses.foldLeft(Seq[GetterSetterPair]()){case (acc, clsSymb) =>
      extractGetterSetterPairs(clsSymb.asClass.toType, acc)
    }
  }

  private def extractGetterSetterPairs(typ: ru.Type, acc: Seq[GetterSetterPair]): Seq[GetterSetterPair] = {
    val terms = typ.declarations.collect{case x if x.isTerm => x.asTerm}
    acc ++ terms.filter{x => x.isGetter}.map{x => x -> x.setter}.
      filter{case(g,s) => s.isTerm}.map{case(g,s) =>
        GetterSetterPair(g,s.asTerm)
      }
  }

  def termName(t: ru.TermSymbol): String = {
    t.name.toString.trim
  }

}

case class GetterSetterPair(getter: ru.TermSymbol, setter: ru.TermSymbol) {
  val name = ReflectionUtils.termName(getter)

  val fieldType = {
    //this is way more complicated than it should be. But
    // 1) getters for some reason are not instances of ru.MethodType
    //        java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.internal.Types$NullaryMethodType cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Types$MethodTypeApi
    // 2) its a headache to get the types out of setters
    val m = setter.typeSignature.
      asInstanceOf[ru.MethodType]
    m.params.head.typeSignature
  }
}
```